# Coolant boiling

Tags: coolant

When I start the engine it was showing me that the coolant level is low. I did buy a mixed antifreeze and put on top of the other. Like in 5 miles when I stopped I did hear a strange noise. I opened the bonnet lid and saw that my coolant is boiling and in a few seconds all was gone by the overflow. Can someone advise please.

Comment: Thanks.... I really appreciate the answer... It was just the right one... It is working.... Thanks once again

Comment: What about a leaky head gasket? Happened to my Ford Taurus.

Answer (score 5):

You likely have trapped air in your coolant/antifreeze system.

But before I tell you how to fix it, please know that you should NOT mix different colours of anti-freeze. They may react and form a thick sludge that can block the system. And that gets difficult or expensive to take care of.

Now, to get rid of the trapped air, all you need to do is

1. Unscrew the cap on the coolant/antifreeze reservoir and start your car.
2. let it run until the fan comes on.
3. turn your aircon up as hot as it can go. (it's quicker to wait for the car to warm up first, otherwise the aircon being on hot will cause the engine to heat up at a slower rate.)
4. turn your aircon's fan up to full blast.
5. watch the coolant reservoir. You'll see bubbles and foam coming into it. wait until the antifreeze comes in at a smooth rate.
6. the anti-freeze level may go down as it replaces the trapped air that escaped. This is normal. Just pour some more in.

Don't forget to pour some water in too. Water is what helps to cool down your car. Antifreeze only guards against freezing and rust. The bottle will tell you how many parts water to antifreeze you should mix.

Fun fact: this is called "burping" your car ;)

UPDATE: as per Mac's comment, a likely cause of the problem you had 5 miles after adding coolant was that the overflow tank cap was not tightened down properly. Be sure to check that twice next time.

Comment: I agree that this is a good course of action to take at this point. I would add that a likely cause of the problem you had 5 miles after adding coolant was that the overflow tank cap was not tightened down properly. Be sure to check that twice next time.

Comment: I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: Since OP did not indicate what car he has at least some BMWs are "burped" by "Turning the ignition to Aux 2, Engine OFF, heater on fan setting 1 and temperature fully hot". Though, I don't know what is the outcome difference between both procedures.

Answer (score 3):

If you had overheating problems before adding the antifreeze/topping up the coolant, then you could be looking at a thermostat problem. Check also for any damage to hoses, radiator and the expansion tank cap. 
In passing, water boils at 100C/212F. A motor vehicle cooling system is maintained by the system at pressure, the pressure prevents the coolant from boiling. If you were to undo any part of the system whilst it's hot, then the release of pressure will enable the water to boil instantly and this will spray boiling water and steam at great force out of the system. Your system cap should carry a warning 'Do not undo when hot'.